# dynamic block size drawbacks

Tags: scalability, blocksize

What are potential long term drawbacks of dynamic block size ? I mean bitcoin for some reason doesn't want to increase and\or make it dynamic. If scaling could be solved with just implementing dynamic block size then why do we have this long bitcoin block size debate?

Answer (score 2):

We could scale to having very large blocks which could lead to it being prohibitively expensive to run a node.  We might be left with a situation of concentration of nodes/ mining.

Answer (score 2):

There is always the possibility that it will become too expensive for people to store and use the blockchain if its size grows too large.

However, with the rate at which storage technology is increasing, I can't imagine that will ever be much of an issue. Not that long ago, it would've been crazy to expect the average person to store an 85 GB blockchain like bitcoin's. But these days 10TB HDDs and multi-TB SSDs are coming ever closer.